# Pentaho - Execute every input row, if fail one row continue

Tags: row, pentaho, execute, continue

I'm creating a ETL but i don't how to do it.

In table input I get my data flow this data can have problems of length, type etc ... Then, I just want to insert correct rows. The uncorrects I just want create error, to be picked up by "Jenkins"
Steps:

1. Transformation: Obtain rows

   1. Table input
   2. Copy rows to result
2. Transformation: Load rows (execute every input row)

   1. Get rows from result
   2. Data Validator
   3. Table output (This in reality is another "copy to rows to result", this data is needed by another table input)

How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@guibos You don't need a datavalidator. Do error handling in table output which will redirect the wrong stream of data into  error table or erroneous file.          OR                                                                                    Do the error handling of Data validator and redirect the data to error table. Please let me know if you need any help.